# Hard Refresh and Data Persistence in Web Browsers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, page-refresh

I wonder what is persisted in the browser after 'hard refresh' (Ctrl+F5) in moder browsers (I'm using Google Chrome)?

Consider the page: http://fxrig.azurewebsites.net/index.html

The footer is displayed on the initial load. Scroll the page up and do hard refresh - the footer is now semi hidden. I presume something gets persisted across hard refresh, wonder what it is.

Comment: localStorage and sessionStorage are made for this, and cookies can be used as well.

Comment: @dandavis none of the above seemed to be involced accrodingly to google dev tools anyway.

Comment: btw should Ctrl+F5 reset sessionStorage? My question is about how Chrom knows that I'm refreshing the window as opposed to navigating to the Ulr for the first time...

Comment: there are lots of other ways to tell return visitors: resource timing, server-side IP tracking, http request headers (w/Date+max-age), client-side storage (flash/sql/indexedDB/silverlight/window.name/etc), and BF cache population for example.

Comment: @dandavis the point is it's my website. I do nothing to track it moreover I don't know how is it possible. I'm trying to remove unwanted scroll the the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, chrome doesn't reset the [`window.scrollY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) variable on hard refresh.
According to my tests on osX, Firefox does.

To prevent this behaviour, you can set a function `window.scrollTo(0,0)` at page load.

Comment: I'm trying to combat a bug whereby the page gets jumped to the bottom upon initial loading and everytime when jQuery.load(...) is called. The jumps are reproducible in Chrome, IE and FF. Wonder if I can fix the jumps by manipulating window.scrollY? Currently if I set it to 0 it disables window scrolling...

Comment: @user1514042 yes, your problem comes from the #contribute that is set up automatically in url and acts as an anchor on the page to go to element with id `contribute`